# Databases that use SQLite as storage layer

Tags: database, sqlite, nosql

What databases use SQLite as their storage layer?

Note: I've learnt that CouchBase in it's early stages used SQLite as it's storage layer but I did not found the code - and I am not sure it's correct because I've read it on some non-official document.

I just want to study the code base of those databases (mostly NoSQL ones) - if there is any - and play around the concept.

Comment: SQLite is a database! If a database used SQLite as its storage layer, then it won't be much of a database. It will be a wrapper around SQLite with a different API.

Comment: In general you are right. But there are - actually - databases (mostly NoSQL ones) that use other databases as their storage system for example RavenDB uses ESENT as it's storage layer and Lucene.NET for generating indexes or datomic uses a mixture of other databases. This way they employ a well established and mature library to take care of storage (of course they inherit all of cons and pros of that technology).

Comment: Libraries like [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) typically aren't called "database".

Comment: You are right Membase and Couchbase 1.8 were using SQLite. In Couchbase 2.0 it is not anymore the case, the persistence has been entirely recreated from scratch on a Append Only file system.

Answer (score 0):

TouchDB uses SQLite as it's back end and it's considered a database.

http://touchdb.org/

In other words, TouchDB at a high level stores JSON documents, so it's a document oriented database. But the actual details of storage are handled by SQLite.

Like all the comments point out, any database that uses SQLite as the back end, generally isn't a database you'd want to use. =)